# How to make sure I stay on Linux kernel version 3.13 (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, update-manager, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday, because my WiFi adapter is not supported in 16.04. I am told this is likely due to the Linux kernel.

In order for my computer's WiFi adapter to work, I'm told I need to be on Linux kernel version 3.13 and no higher.

I've since installed all of the available updates in Software Updater, and am now on Ubuntu 14.04.4.

My question is: How do I ensure that I don't inadvertently upgrade my kernel beyond version 3.13? (I've heard about LTS Enablement Stack packages, but am not sure what they are, or where they will appear, so that I can avoid them.)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me what you get when you type in `uname -r` into the terminal? If you just freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 then I think you're on a later kernel release (but with your wifi working - so the '3.13 and no higher' information may be incorrect)

Comment: When I type 'uname -r' into the Terminal, it gives me '3.13.0-86-generic'. Also, of note is that I started with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1, and installed all available updates from there.

Comment: Is you trying to install on a HP laptop?

Comment: No, I'm on a desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are on 3.13 right now, you will stay on that kernel (possible with minor updates) the only reason you would get a newer kernel, is if you downloaded 14.04.4 or something else. You CAN upgrade it though, see here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack .. But if you don't do anything, you will be fine :)

Comment: Hi there, Although I started with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1, I've updated through Software Updater to 14.04.4 (it didn't really tell me it would be updating my point release). But when I type 'uname -r' in Terminal, it tells me I'm on kernel version '3.13.0-86-generic'. Will I stay on version 3.13 and be okay?

Comment: It still will never update your kernel, if you don't choose to do with (with the commands from the link). So no need to worry. Also IF it should happen you do it by mistake, it will still keep your old kernel and you can then just remove the "new" one.

Comment: That's great to know, thank you for your helpfulness!

Answer (score 1):

This page has several methods for sticking to a specific kernel version
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

The simplest option being to hold it

```
sudo apt-get hold linux-image-3.13
```

Comment: That would be really bad, since he would not get any security updates. He will stay on 3.13 without that.

Comment: That sounds cool. But I *would* like to continue receiving security updates until the LTS's end of life if possible. Someone else recommended Grub Customizer. But isn't there a simple way to revert back to an older kernel on your system in Ubuntu, or using the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Grub Customizer to select the default boot kernel (without having to manually press SHIFT and load GRUB list).

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/

```
General settings --> Default boot
```

.

Comment: Hey, that's a really helpful resource! Thank you, I'll make a note of it. I just have to make sure I don't 'sudo apt-get autoclean', 'clean' or 'autoremove' and delete my previous kernels.